# What does "for him to affect the race" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the paragraph in which "for him to affect the race" occurs:

> But even if the fund ends up flopping, it will have several lasting
>   effects on technology investing. The first is that the deployment of
>   so much cash now will help shape the industries of the future. Mr Son
>   is pumping money into “frontier technologies” from robotics to the
>   internet of things. He already owns stakes in ride-hailing firms such
>   as Uber; in WeWork, a co-working company; and in Flipkart, an Indian
>   e-commerce firm that was this week sold to Walmart (see article). In
>   five years’ time the fund plans to have invested in 70-100 technology
>   unicorns, privately held startups valued at $1bn or more. Its money,
>   often handed to entrepreneurs in multiples of the amounts they
>   initially demand and accompanied by the threat that the cash will go
>   to the competition if they balk, gives startups the wherewithal to
>   outgun worse-funded rivals. **Mr Son’s bets do not have to pay off for
>   him to affect the race.**

Could someone explain why Mr. Son's investment does not have to pay off for him to affect the race?

[Source](https://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21741973-succeed-or-fail-masayoshi-son-changing-world-technology-investing-meaning): *The Economist*: 12 May 2018 issue, The meaning of the Vision Fund

Comment: It’s explained in the first sentences quoted.

Answer (score 0):

As Jim said in the comments, it’s repetition and reiteration of the first sentence in the paragraph. Simply by funding one company, other non-funded companies close (because of the competition). The funded company doesn’t have to return a profit, they might go bust, too, but the non-funded competition will go out of business faster. So Mr Son doesn’t have to see a return on his investment (win his bet) to indirectly put unfunded companies out of business (affect the race).